# In a Banach space $Y$, if $y_n \stackrel{w}{\longrightarrow} z$ and there is a subsequence $y_{n_k} \rightarrow z$, can we prove $y_n \rightarrow z$?

Tags: functional-analysis

I saw such statement in a book: $Y$ is a Banach space, $\{y_n\} \subset Y$, if $y_n \stackrel{w}{\longrightarrow} z$ and there exists a subsequence $y_{n_k} \rightarrow z$(converge in norm, or strongly converge), then $y_n \rightarrow z$. I can't figure out how to prove the statement, and I searched through google and found no similar statement. So is it true or can we find a counter-example?

Comment: In $\ell_2$, take $y_{2n}=e_{2n}$ and $y_{2n+1}=0$. Then $(y_n)$ converges weakly to the zero vector and has a subsequence converging in norm to the zero vector. But ...

Comment: Great! I will choose it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not true.

For example, in $\ell_2$, take $y_{2n}=e_{2n}$, where $e_i$ is the standard $i^{\rm th}$ unit vector, and $y_{2n+1}=\bf{0}$. Then $(y_n)$ converges weakly to the zero vector and has a subsequence converging in norm to the zero vector.  Of course, $(y_n)$ is not norm-convergent.